# como firmar un xml con xml signature

Tags: php, xml

Mi problemática es firmar un xml para obtener los valores de digest y digestvalue con unos certificados https en el consumo de un ws, la persona que lo solicita nos facilito un ejemplo en donde usa un keystore hasta donde he leído este archivo solo es valido en java como pudiera hacer esto en php o c#?

en el soapui lo que se me paso de ejemplo es.Agregar el keystore en esta parte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

después en la petición se realiza esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y listo en soap ui ahi ya lo firma y es valido pero no puedo replicar lo mismo con php.

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias y saludos.

Comment: Luis Fernando ¿conseguiste hacerlo? yo tengo un problema similar y estoy atascado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que logro entender creo que yo hice algo similar en C#.
Tuve que consumir un web service que recibía una solicitud firmada con un certificado y me retornaba un token.

- Tuve que construir el xml correspondiente a la solicitud del token
- En mi caso los nodos estaban relacionados es decir tienes que generar el digest de un Timespan(en mi caso) y ese digest se inserta en el nodo siguiente, ese nodo incluye información del certificado y ahora se con la llave privada firmaras el nodo que tiene el primer digest y la info del certificado.
- Yo no instale el certifcado en el store simplemente lo leía desde una ruta especifica pero tampoco es complicado recuperarlo.